# why does python consume so much memory and never release it

Tags: python, memory

Why does my program keep consuming memory and never release it? If you try to run it, you will know what I mean.

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/env python
 
def is_prime(num):
    if num <= 1: return False
    if num != 2 and num % 2 == 0: return False
 
    to = num / 2 + 1
    for x in range(3, to, 2):
        if num % x == 0: return False
    return True
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    primes = []
    for x in range(2, 100):
        if is_prime(x): primes.append(x)
    print(primes)
     
    product = primes[0]
    for i in range(1, len(primes)):
        print("prime: " + str(primes[i]))
        new_prime = product * primes[i] + 1
        if is_prime(new_prime):
            print("new prime: " + str(new_prime))
        else:
            print(str(new_prime) + " is not prime! [error]")
        product *= primes[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that python2 has memory leak. Python3 won't have this issue.